# Save datas to socketio

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to save datas (simple type, like strings and ints) to a socket in my Socket.IO app. Before the 1.0 version, i was using `io.get()` and `io.set()` but they're depreciated now.

Any update on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of `1.0` you can directly set/read it to/from the client, which is passed to a callback of the event (at least I did not find any other option):

```
io.sockets.on("event", function(client) {
    client['foo'] = bar;
});
```

There is also no callback when you read a property anymore, so you can simply get it in the same way:

```
io.sockets.on("event", function(client) {
    var bar = client['foo'];
});
```

Comment: In your example, client is the socket returned by `io.sockets.on("connection", function(client) { ...` ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Fine, thanks a lot, it seems way more fluent this way.